# Calling External Azure Function (Blob Trigger Function) from inside the Data Factory using pipeline activities

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I am using Azure Data Factory
I am creating pipeline.
This pipeline needs to call Azure Function "AF-ReadBlob-from-AzureBlob-WriteToDatabase".
The Azure Function is created outside the Azure Factory as it has complex rules, and this "AF-ReadBlob-from-AzureBlob-WriteToDatabase" is already blob trigger.

Now I want to call above Azure Function from Data Factory using "Activities Azure Function."
But under setting, I have to put Method (Get, Post etc.)
Since my Azure Function is blob trigger, I don't have such method to call.

Please advise me how can I resolve this issue?

FYI: I did not way to deploy my Azure Function directly inside Azure Data Factory.
I only choice I have is to call it using pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

There can be only one triggertype (restapi / blob) for an azure function.

Either you change the trigger from Blob to RestAPI in order to invoke the function via restAPI Call

Or, if you want to stay with blob trigger, then you can upload some file using adf into storage account.